# PLINQ result is wrong and varies in different run

Tags: c#, plinq

I am learning PLINQ. I tried on example given on a site. However I can see that the result is wrong and also varies when I re-run the program many times. First it does not gives all prime numbers and second it gives only 9591 random prime numbers.

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range (3, 100000-3);

var parallelQuery = 
  from n in numbers.AsParallel()
  where Enumerable.Range (2, (int) Math.Sqrt (n)).All (i => n % i > 0)
  select n;

int[] primes = parallelQuery.ToArray();
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: In what way does it vary? The order of the numbers can vary, because you do not sort them.

Comment: From 3 to (100000-3), there are prime numbers more than 9591 but it shows only 9591 prime numbers, not rest.

Comment: You range does not include 2, look at my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 9592 prime numbers below 100,000, and your range does not include 2, which is a prime number.

The order of the prime numbers will vary, because you do not sort them, and have no control over how PLINQ splits the work into parallel chunks.

Comment: Thanks Kaerber. I was comparing PLINQ and traditional thread. In my traditional thread logic, there was some problem, so I was getting wrong (more prime numbers i.e. redundant) results.